# How do I add Docker to my modular web application

Tags: java, ubuntu, docker

Firstly I am new to docker and most times I see articles on adding jars to docker but my project is modular and below are the list of modules apart from ng client the rest have jar files and the parent package

```
dao
dao-api
model
ng-client
rest-client
rest-producer
service
service-api
test-db
utility
valen-ezu  (this is the parent module cantaining all modules above)
```

How can put everything in docker correctly and be able to run it rest-producer has a war, not jar, Can I get a step by step approach I am on an ubuntu os I have installed docker and I created a file Dockerfile in the directory of this app

In my Dockerfile I have

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD - what next?
```

I have so many jars and war so can I get an explanation as to how to go about it

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct your build produces a war, that being the case you need an application server. Tomcat could be a good choice, so I would suggest to start by extending your custom image from the official [Tomcat Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/).

Then in your `Dockerfile` copy the war to the `webapps` home directory `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/`. A basic example:

```
FROM tomcat
COPY rest-producer.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Comment: it is a jetty server should i just change the tomcat to jetty? @bOgusb

Comment: You could use jetty as well. [Jetty Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/jetty/). Reading the docs you should replace `/usr/loca/tomcat/webapps` with `/var/lib/jetty/webapps`

Comment: suggest to start by extending your custom image from the official Tomcat Docker image.  how do i do this ? i am in the site , 7.0.88-jre7 such numbers are there ? i copy it to dockerfile?

Comment: and by the this would be located in a dockerfile that is in the rest-producer module and i should do something similar for the jars of services and dao ? what next

Comment: I am not sure what the dao and services are used for. In case you have other war files or services you should consider deploying them too in Docker containers. You should better describe your final goal in the question.